# Get SharePoint List Items using SharePoint Framework React

Tags: error, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, react

I am getting SharePoint list items using framework react with following code:

[Developing SharePoint Framework Web Parts Using ReactJS](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/developing-sharepoint-framework-web-parts-using-react-js-part-two/)

```
import * as React from 'react';  
import { css } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';  
import styles from './Splistitems.module.scss';  
import { ISplistitemsProps } from './ISplistitemsProps';  
import * as jquery from 'jquery';   

export interface ISplistitemsState{  
  items:[  
        {  
          "Title":string           
        }]  
}  


export default class Splistitems extends React.Component<ISplistitemsProps, void> {
    public constructor(props: ISplistitemsProps, state: ISplistitemsState){  
        super(props);  
        this.state = {  // This `this.state` throws error
          items: [  
            {  
              "Title": ""           
            }  
          ]  
        };  
      } 

public componentWillMount(){ 
//..
//..
}
public render(): React.ReactElement<IUpcomingEventsProps> {
//..
//..
}
}
```

Here, line `this.state` throws following error:

> Type '{ items: { "Title": string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type
>   'void'.

what is the problem ??

Comment: can you change `super(props); ` to `super(); ` and check ?

Comment: Not working....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There  will be return type `ISplistitemsState` instead of `void` in `Splistitems` class.

**Change following line**

```
export default class Splistitems extends React.Component<ISplistitemsProps, void> {
```

**To**

```
export default class Splistitems extends React.Component<ISplistitemsProps, ISplistitemsState> {
```